# Angular bootstrap returning setIsOpen is not a function

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

We've got the following HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group search-dropdown" dropdown is-open="gender.isopen">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
    {{sex_temp=='F'?'Female':'Male'}} <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li ng-class="{'dropdown-selected':sex_temp=='F'}">
                    <a ng-click="sex_temp='F'">Female</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{'dropdown-selected':sex_temp=='M'}">
                    <a ng-click="sex_temp='M'">Male</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the console, we're getting the following error:

```
Error: setIsOpen is not a function @http://127.0.0.1/lib/bootstrap-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js:1734:5
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://127.0.0.1/lib/AngularJS/angular.js:12406:23
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://127.0.0.1/lib/AngularJS/angular.js:12679:13
done@http://127.0.0.1/lib/AngularJS/angular.js:8279:34
completeRequest@http://127.0.0.1/lib/AngularJS/angular.js:8484:7
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://127.0.0.1/lib/AngularJS/angular.js:8423:1 @debugger eval code:1:1
consoleLog/<@http://127.0.0.1/lib/AngularJS/angular.js:10062:18
$ExceptionHandlerProvider/this.$get</<@http://127.0.0.1/lib/AngularJS/angular.js:7363:7
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://127.0.0.1/lib/AngularJS/angular.js:12426:19
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://127.0.0.1/lib/AngularJS/angular.js:12679:13
done@http://127.0.0.1/lib/AngularJS/angular.js:8279:34
completeRequest@http://127.0.0.1/lib/AngularJS/angular.js:8484:7
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://127.0.0.1/lib/AngularJS/angular.js:8423:1
```

We're using ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js

I have tried adding `$scope.gender={isopen:false}` but that didn't help.

Any idea on what might be the problem here?  The dropdown is working perfectly. I just want to get rid of these errors in the console.

Comment: it cleary says `setIsOpen is not a function`

Comment: Which Angular version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I believe it has something to do with the overlap of bootstrap's drop-down. Try removing the "dropdown-toggle" class from your button.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to simply remove the `is-open` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is 2 years later, but updating your ui-bootstrap would fix this problem if you're using an older version (example 0.13 instead of 2.5)